# Advance Filter Hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Used Advanced Filter to create a filter on a separate wksht in same workbook. Within the list range are cells that have hyperlinks. The advanced filter is on brings all of Row 1, Row 2, etc to sheet. Column named Title brings in the string without a hyperlink attached to it. How do I bring hyperlink onto Sheet along with all of other info.

Macro below for clarity:

```
Sub Filterme() Filterme Macro 
' 
' 
  Sheet10.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, 
  _   CriteriaRange:=Range("FilterData!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range( 
  _ "FilterData!Extract"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `Action:=xlFilterCopy`, obtain the (potentially discontinuous) range of the filtered rows via `Action:=xlFilterInPlace` and then copy the results before resetting the visible filter. The following code applies an advanced filter to data on `Sheet1` using criteria located in the range `A1:B2` affecting rows starting at `A7`, and then copies the filter results to `Sheet3` before clearing the filter on `Sheet1`:

```
Sub FilterIt()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("$A$1:$B$2"), _
        Unique:=False
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
    Rng.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub Filterme()
'
' Filterme Macro
' Advanced filter
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
'
    Dim Rng As Range
    Worksheets("Sheet10").Activate     - code stops here
    Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("FilteredData!Criteria"), _
        Unique:=False
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
    Worksheets("Sheet10").ShowAllData
    Rng.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Comment: @Deepa is your Sheet10 worksheet hidden? If so, you will need to temporarily make it visible within the macro: `Worksheets("Sheet10").Visible = True`, then set the flag back to false before the macro ends. Otherwise, can you provide the error that is generated when it stops?